# Move the map when the cursor gets close to the edge of map in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I built a selection tool using the `Rectangle` shape tool. You can select markers by drawing a rectangle over them and releasing erases the rectangle (just like selecting things on a desktop OS).

This works great except that Google Maps doesn't pan when you get to the edge of the map so you can't continue your selection if it's just off the screen. Just like if you are selecting text on a web page and you select text below the fold it scrolls down.

I know how to pan and center a map but I'm not sure how to use those to get a smooth scroll feeling as you get to the edges of the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a much more performant, better, cleaner way to handle this but this is what I ended up using:

```
/**
 * This pans the map when the user is moused down and at the end of the map
 * bounding box.
 *
 * @return {undefined}
 */
DrawingManager.prototype._mapPanHandler = function (googleMapEvent) {
  var self = this;
  var event = googleMapEvent;

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);

  var projection = overlay.getProjection();
  var pixelpoint = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(map.getCenter());

  var proj = overlay.getProjection();
  var thepix = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(event.latLng);

  var nE = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  var sW = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
  var nE = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(nE);
  var sW = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(sW);

  var north = nE.y;
  var east  = nE.x;
  var south = sW.y;
  var west  = sW.x;

  var appx_north, appx_east, appx_south, appx_west;

  if (Math.round(thepix.y) <= Math.round(north + 50)) {appx_north = true;}
  if (Math.round(thepix.x) >= Math.round(east  - 50)) {appx_east  = true;}
  if (Math.round(thepix.y) >= Math.round(south - 50)) {appx_south = true;}
  if (Math.round(thepix.x) <= Math.round(west  + 50)) {appx_west  = true;}

  clearInterval(self._panTimer);

  if (!appx_north && !appx_east && !appx_south && !appx_west) {
    return;
  }

  var panMap = function () {
    var movementAmount = 3;
    if (appx_north) { pixelpoint.y -= movementAmount; }
    if (appx_east)  { pixelpoint.x += movementAmount; }
    if (appx_south) { pixelpoint.y += movementAmount; }
    if (appx_west)  { pixelpoint.x -= movementAmount; }
    point = projection.fromDivPixelToLatLng(pixelpoint);
    map.setCenter(point);
  }

  panMap();
  self._panTimer = setInterval(panMap, 10);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the 8 additional rectangles on the screen, they are trasparent, maybe possitioned absolute with js support will be good idea.

[image]

While user is selecting:

```
If users mouse is on area1 -> go north-west (code it)
If users mouse is on area2 -> go north (code it)
If users mouse is on area3 -> go north-east (code it)
If users mouse is on area4 -> go east (code it)
If users mouse is on area5 -> go south-east (code it)
If users mouse is on area6 -> go south (code it)
If users mouse is on area7 -> go south-west (code it)
If users mouse is on area8 -> go west (code it)
```

If map can be rotated - you have to adjust the scrolling.

If you wanna go for the smooth animation you can do...
For example of area1: take y axis and compare it to mouse position and adjust acceleration and min/max speed.
For corners you can go for normal point-to-point distance math.

After all you can declare radial acceleration, but I think it will crash low-spec smartphones if app is also delivered for it.

Comment: But how do I move the map smoothly to match the user's movement? If I "center" the map to (for example) `area1` it'll just jump up to that not smoothly. If I animate it it'll animate at a totally different speed then the user's mouse is going

Comment: Saw your edit, and yeah that's how I've done it before and works fine on smartphones but you can't scroll like a normal webpage. You can't compare the y axis like that. You need to use center or pan (afaik) and those you need to use LatLng, not the pixel values. If you pan to the area1 LatLng it's going to jump and center the map to the center of area1 which isn't what anyone would expect.

Comment: Old code would just be normal divs like: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/pAu8Q/ but that wont work with google maps. Im not sure how to scroll in that manner in google maps

Comment: I will help when I arrive home.